# display more divs float right with scroll

Tags: html, css

I am trying to load more components in one div with `float: right` and use the scroll bar (horizontally) in order to see all the data that now is displayed vertically

here is my code

```
    <div class="right view-calendar">
        <ca-month-header *ngFor="let selectedMonth of selectedMonths" [viewDate]="selectedMonth"> 
        </ca-month-header>
    </div>
```

and my styles

```
.right {
    float: right;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.view-header {
    width: 180px;
}
```

This is how my page looks now if I want to display 4  components
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For overflow on Y axis to work you need to set a height/max-height to that element. And then use `overflow-y` .Using just `overflow` will cause a horizontal scroll aswell

see example below

Also i would suggest against using `float` for layout. As it was never intended to be used for this and it gets the elements out of the normal flow of the document. Take a look at `flexBox` or `cssGrid` for layout.

```css
.right {
height: 200px;
overflow-y:scroll;
float:right;
}

.right div {
height:50px;
background:red;
width:100px;
}
.right div:nth-child(odd) {
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was talking for scroll on the X axis... I tried overflow-x: scroll with a width:1000px and the result is the same as I've posted on this question.... is there another solution?

Comment: you could try to add a wrapper around `.right` and add to that `width:1000px` and `overflow-x:scroll` . I cannot replicate your problem without more code from you